# Свойство prototype

Tags: javascript

Привет!

Есть 2 объекта

```
var x={color:red}
var y={foo:'bar',hoo:3}
```

Как через прототип скопировать все свойства объекта y в x. Для новых браузеров все ок через   *proto*, а для ие через prototype не сображу как.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Object.prototype.extend = function( o ) {
  for( var i in o ) {
    if( o.hasOwnProperty(i) ) {
      this[i] = o[i];
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
var x={ color: 'red' };
var y={ foo  : 'bar', hoo:3 };
x.extend( y );
console.log( x );
```

Comment: Да здесь же 5 строк кода ( если сжать, вообще 3 =) )
Если не знаете цикла `for in` - погуглите и почитайте, если не знаете метода hasOwnProperty - аналогично. Остальное должно быть понятным (собственно там больше ничего и нет)

Пожалуйста

Comment: @zloctb, если ваша проблема решена - не забудьте принять ответ.

Comment: @zloctb, и поставить плюсик, как я сейчас сделал.

Comment: @uWeb - это уже по желанию =)

Comment: походу разобрался!Ошибки исправил!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой метод:

```
Object.prototype.clone = function () {
    var instance = {};
    for (i in this) {
        if (i == 'clone') continue;
        if (this[i] && typeof this[i] == "object") {
            instance[i] = this[i].clone();
        } else instance[i] = this[i]
    }
    return instance;
};
```

Comment: Этот бред - правильный ответ?О_О

Я спрашиваю потому, что реально не могу понять - какой смысл этого кода...